# Как сделать скриншот страницы сайта?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Как можно делать, скриншоты страниц сайтов без посторонних сервисов которые делают скриншоты. Скрипт нужен очень простой, без больших библиотек и плагинов. Что можете посоветовать ?

Answer (score 1):

Я когда то тестировал [4 библиотеки](http://jeka.by/post/1029/screenshots/) создания скриншотов:

1. Webscreenie
2. PhantomJs
3. PythonWebkit2Png
4. WkHtml

В целом результаты их работы похожи. Где то html рендерит лучше одна, где то другая.

Например, [robothumb.com](http://robothumb.com/) этот проект генерит скриншоты с помощью **webscreenie**. webscreenie одна из самых старых библиотек, но при этом работает довольно таки не плохо.

У **phantomJs** очень большие возможности. Рендеринг html и cоздание скриншота - это только капля в море. Под неё нужно писать код на javascript.

Можно остановиться на **python-webkit2png**. Либа достаточно легко собирается.

```
apt-get install python-qt4 libqt4-webkit xvfb python-setuptools
cd /opt
git clone https://github.com/adamn/python-webkit2png.git python-webkit2png
cd python-webkit2png
python setup.py install
```

Код создания скриншота из консоли с помощью webkit2png:

```
webkit2png -x 1000 1000 --geometry=1000 1000 --output=/tmp/output.png --timeout=10 http://example.com/
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть хорошее хром расширение которое умеет заливать на сервер и давать урл картинки https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/picflipio-1-screenshot-ca/emdjgaadafkmimgiifodbpgoceclbfjb

Answer (score 0):

Я использую  [Full Page screen capture](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/full-page-screen-capture/fdpohaocaechififmbbbbbknoalclacl?hl=ru)

Answer (score 0):

Такую вещь уже пытались решить, и вроде как решили:
на [stackoverflow: Using HTML5/Canvas/JavaScript to take screenshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-screenshots/6678156#6678156)

Так же, можно использовать Node.js c прикрученным к нему PhantomJS у которого есть [Screen Capture](http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html)

Answer (score 0):

Использую приложение [Захват экрана](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/screen-capture/ghihpjhpgdepnohngpgfcmcijmkggpaf/related), Гугл его сам советовал в своей [справке](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/100070?hl=ru)